# Find a power series of $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ to show it is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know what the power series of $\sin z$ and $\frac{1}{z}$ separately, but I'm not sure how to put them together. Also, I am assuming that when $z=0$ implies $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}=1$. I'm not sure if you just have to multiply the power series of the functions together or if there is a more efficient way to use a power series to find it is analytic.

Answer (score 2):

Take the power series of $\sin z$ and divide it by $z$:
$$\frac{\sin z}z=\frac{z-z^3/6+\cdots}z=1-z^2/6+\cdots$$

Comment: @allthatmath As an exercise, you can show that this is equivalent to what you get when you multiply the two power series and collect terms of the same degree :)